# Is the set of triangle centers given by polynomial functions dense?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, polynomials

Given a function $f$ that satisfies:

- Homogeneity: $f(tx,ty,tz) = t^nf(x,y,z)$ for some $n$ and any $x,y,z$.
- Bisymmetric in the second and third variables: $f(x,y,z) = f(x,z,y)$.

We say that the point with trilinear coordinates $f(a,b,c):f(b,c,a):f(c,a,b)$ is a center of the triangle with sides $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Let us restrict ourselves to polynomial functions $f$ and scalene triangles $(a > b > c > 0$). Is the set of triangle centers dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

*Remark:* without the restriction stated before, any point in the plane is a center.

Comment: Hi, what are the properties of the density of triangle centers? I mean, why do you need to verify if the set of triangle centers is dense or not? (I'm learning about the triangle centers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say **yes**.

Suppose two points $P$ and $Q$ are triangle centers. Then the midpoint $R$ between $P$ and $Q$ is a triangle center as well:

$$f_R=(a\,f_P(a,b,c)+b\,f_P(b,c,a)+c\,f_P(c,a,b))\cdot f_Q\\
+(a\,f_Q(a,b,c)+b\,f_Q(b,c,a)+c\,f_Q(c,a,b))\cdot f_P$$

The reflection $S$ of $P$ in $Q$ is a center as well; its trilinears can be computed using

$$f_S=2(a\,f_P(a,b,c)+b\,f_P(b,c,a)+c\,f_P(c,a,b))\cdot f_Q\\
-(a\,f_Q(a,b,c)+b\,f_Q(b,c,a)+c\,f_Q(c,a,b))\cdot f_P$$

Taken together, these two can be used to turn an arbitrary pair of distinct centers into a dense set of centers on the line spanned by these two centers. Let's call one of the points “$0$” and the other “$1$” and consider these as defininig a scale. In any $\varepsilon$ environment on the line there will be a scale mark of the form $\pm\frac{m}{2^k}$. W.l.o.g. the sign is positive (else change the roles of $0$ and $1$). So reflect $i$ in $i+1$ till you reach $m$, then $k$ times take the midpoint between that point and $0$. Other ways to combine the operations of “extend by reflection” and “zoom in using midpoints” are possible.

If you do this not only for two centers, but for three non-collinear ones, you can combine them to get arbitrarily close to any point in the plane. So as long as you can show that a scalene triangle always has three non-collinear centers, you get a dense set of centers.

The way I came up with the above formulas is by considering homogeneous coordinates in a projective plane embedded at $z=1$. The midpoint of points $[x_A:y_A:1]$ and $[x_B:y_B:1]$ is $[x_A+x_B:y_A+y_B:2]$. But this simple addition relies on the representatives having the same $z$ coordinate. So more generally the midpoint of $A=[x_A:y_A:z_A]$ and $B=[x_B:y_B:z_B]$ is $z_B\cdot A+z_A\cdot B$. This relies on the specific embedding at $z=1$, which can also be seen as the position of the line at infinity $l_\infty=[0:0:1]$. If one does not pick specific coordinates for that line, the midpoint could be written as $\langle l_\infty,B\rangle\cdot A+\langle l_\infty,A\rangle\cdot B$. This equation no longer depends on the choice of basis. Trilinear coordinates are just another basis for the projective plane, and the line at infinity in that basis is $[a:b:c]$. This I read from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates#Parallel_lines). So the parentheses given above are these scalar products between the line at infinity and the trilinears of one of the points. The same ideas hold for the reflection.